# Using itextpdf with KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh Font

Tags: itextpdf

i am required to use the Font : KFGQPC Uthman Taha Naskh wich is the font used to write the holy Quraan, you can find more information about the font in this [link](http://fonts.qurancomplex.gov.sa/).

Now you can use the exact Same Sample of [say_peace](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=205) used in itextpdf site

and change the Arabic font from: "arialuni.ttf" to "UthmanTN1 Ver09.otf"

the output is 90% Ok but unfortionatly the letters are not complete for Arabic.

Can anyone please guide me twardes solving this problem.

Best Regards 
Ibrahim Bakhsh

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved this problem by editing the font and adding the missing encoding

it was very complicated process. and somehow new adventure for me.

Thanks anywhay

Best Regards 
Ibrahim Bakhsh
Mobile: +966503737278